# Creating ( not truly ) random array of integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to write a code that generates an array of random integers in Java which should hold 256 integers and where the values of integers are somewhere between 0 - 512(It could be 0 - 256 or 0 - 1024 but not 0 - 1 million something.. ) . However, every time I run this code, I should get the same randomized array.

This is what I have:

```
int k = 256;

for(int t=0;t<k;t++){
    Random rn = new Random(t);
    int randomNumber = rn.nextInt();
    arrayToBeSorted[t] = randomNumber;
}
```

However, this gives me values like:

```
-1155484576 -1155869325 -1154715079 -1155099828 -1157023572
```

which I do not like at all.

So I change my code to this: ( I add k*2 as a paramter to nextInt method )

```
for(int t=0;t<k;t++){
    Random rn = new Random(t);
    int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(k*2);
    arrayToBeSorted[t] = randomNumber;
}
```

And now this is what I get:

```
374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 374 374 375 375 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 374 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 372 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 373 372 372 373 373 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 370 370 371 370 370 370 370 370 372 372 372 372 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 371 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 369 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 369 370 370 380 380 380 380 379 379 380 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 380 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 378 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 379 378 379 379 378 378 378 378 377 377 377 377 377 376 377 377 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 377 377 378 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 377 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 376 375 375 375 375
```

What I do not like about this is, there are way to many values that are repeating. So what should I do?

*Note: I also need to this 10 times actually. So;

1. In my code, I will have another counter on top of all this which counts from 0 to 9, say **int = c;**
2. I need all these 10 arrays to be randomized, in range of 0 to 1024 (max).

Thank you.

Comment: Use an RNG that accepts a seed and always use the same seed.

Comment: @HotLicks What is an RNG?

Comment: Random Number Generator. In fact, for this to work, it must be a Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG)

Comment: Random Number Generator.  And note that you SHOULD NOT be creating a new RNG every iteration.  Create one outside the loop (and init it with your seed) and then do nextInt for each new random number.

Comment: `Random` does, just pass it upon construction.

Comment: @JBNizet - Picky, picky.  (But good point)

Comment: PRNG? http://www.xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to anticipate on the next question: what is a PRNG?

Comment: Pseudorandom generator: generated numbers are not really random (for that, you need a physical source of entropy, like alpha-decay or junction noise), but they are uniformly distributed and they repeat with such a long period that they can be treated as non-repetitive for most applications. Since there is a deterministic algorithm, if you recreate the starting conditions, you will have the same sequence. The starting state is represented by parameter `seed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
int k = 256;
Random rn = new Random(seed); // use a single Random object, you choose a seed
                              // to get the same sequence, use the same seed

for (int t = 0; t < k; t++) {
    // Random rn = new Random(t); // commented out from your original code
                                  // you only need one Random object
    int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(256); // 256, or whatever you want the max
                                        // value to be
    arrayToBeSorted[t] = randomNumber;
}
```

> Note: I also need to this 10 times actually

Then just repeat the `for` loop 10 times, and using the same `Random` object, like this:

```
int k = 256;
Random rn = new Random(seed);

for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < k; t++) {
        int randomNumber = rn.nextInt(256);
        someArrayOfTenArrays[c][t] = randomNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: And, to get a repeatable series of values, save and reuse the value of `seed`.